# Fancybox with button click to who google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fancybox

I want to use fancybox to show a big map (google maps). This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="fancyLaunch" value="open fancybox" onclick='$("#divMapaGlobal").trigger("click");'/>
<div id="divMapaGlobal">
    <div id="divMapa" class="googleMapsMunicipios">
        <div id="map_canvas_1" class="mapa_canvas"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="capas_mapa">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked id="Capa_1" onclick="chequearCapas();" />
            <label>Capa 1</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked id="Capa_2" onclick="chequearCapas();" />
            <label>Capa 2</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked id="Capa_3" onclick="chequearCapas();" />
            <label>Capa 3</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#divMapaGlobal").fancybox({
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '100%',
        'autoSize': false,
                    
        'afterShow': function(){
            document.getElementById("divMapaGlobal").style.height="85%";
            document.getElementById("divMapa").style.height="100%";
            //document.getElementById("capas_mapa").style.height="80%";
            google.maps.event.trigger(map_1, "resize");
            chequearCapas();
        },
                    
        'onCleanup': function() {
            var myContent = this.href;
            $(myContent).unwrap();
        }, // fixes inline bug
                    
        'afterClose': function () {
            document.getElementById("divMapaGlobal").removeAttribute("style");
            document.getElementById("divMapa").removeAttribute("style");
            //document.getElementById("capas_mapa").removeAttribute("style");
            initialize_1();
            chequearCapas();
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

This code show a google map in fullscreen mode, with some checkboxes to show or hide a layer. I need the checkboxes to also be in fancybox. My problem is with `TRIGGER "CLICK"`, if I check any checkbox, it works like button click.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andynedine/tvVd2/) isn't like my real code, but it can serve. If you click on a checkbox, fancybox must not close.

How can I use fancybox with a button and some html code extra??

Sorry for my english :/